# Limitations on the difference of coprime composites less than $n^2$ for ascertaining primality?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $q$ be a prime where $n < q < n^2$.

Let $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k$ be all the primes $\leq n$.

Is it true that for any $q$, you can find two numbers $a,b$ where $a+b=q$ or $a-b=q$, such that $p_k \# \mid ab$, and where each $p_{i\leq k}$ divides exactly one of $a$ or $b$?

For example, let $q=83$. One solution would be

$$\begin{align}a= 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 17 \cdot 23=383180 \\
b= 3\cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 47=383097\end{align}$$

where $a-b=83$. In this example, since every prime through $23$ is represented in one term or the other, any difference we can obtain below $29^2$ will automatically be a prime. I'll grant this is not stunningly efficient, but I'm still left wondering whether constructions like this are possible for arbitrarily large primes.

It's probably worth mentioning that it is also possible to use the same approach with more than two terms; if we are adding $r$ terms, it works so long as every $p_{i\leq k}$ is present in exactly $r-1$ of them.

Comment: Why not take $a=\prod p_i$?  Then $b=q-a$ is certainly prime to all the $p_i$.

Comment: @lulu You should consider giving an answer based on your comment.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  Well, I can't imagine that that construction is what the OP was hoping for.   That said, I can't really see what the goal was here.

Comment: @lulu You're right this is not likely what the OP wanted. In case they were looking for if it's true for any particular partition of the first $k$ primes among $a$ and $b$, I've given an answer showing it's the case.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I should have said that you haven't actually picked the prime $q$ *a priori*; the motivation is to find the coprime $a,b$ pair where they're close enough in size that their difference is less than $p_k^2$, giving you a number ($q$) which must be prime.

Comment: Yeah, since you didn't say any of that, it wasn't possible to guess what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with any partition of the primes among $a$ and $b$. Choose any subset of the primes $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k$ and let their product be $x$. Also, have the product of the non-chosen primes be $y$. Note if no primes are chosen for a value, then use $1$. Thus, $xy = p_k \#$.

Since $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) states there are integers $c,d$ such that

$$cx + dy = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

As stated in the linked page, you can use a method like the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to determine a pair of $c$ and $d$ for \eqref{eq1}.

Note $\gcd(c,y) = 1$, so no primes which divide $y$ divide $c$, and likewise $\gcd(d,x) = 1$ so no primes which divide $x$ divide $d$. Next, multiply both sides by the prime $q$ to get

$$qcx + qdy = q \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

$$a = qcx \; \text{ and } \; b = qdy \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Thus, $a + b = q$, $p_k \# \mid ab$, and each $p_{i\leq k}$ divides exactly one of $a$ or $b$.

There are actually an infinite number of $a$ and $b$ values which work. Let

$$f = e(p_k \#), \; e \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

$$a_1 = a + f \; \text{ and } \; b_1 = b - f \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

You have, as before, that $x \mid a_1$, $\gcd(y, a_1) = 1$, $y \mid b_1$ and $\gcd(x, b_1) = 1$. Thus, $a_1 + b_1 = q$, $p_k \# \mid a_1 b_1$, and each $p_{i\leq k}$ divides exactly one of $a_1$ or $b_1$. If you prefer to not have $q$ be a factor of $a_1$ or $b_1$, just choose $e$ in \eqref{eq4} so $q \not\mid e$.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful, but unless I'm misunderstanding, it's not exactly what I was looking for; I guess my main question is more to do with how similar in size a partitioned primorial can be. See my comment above, hopefully I've explained it a little better this time.

Comment: @Trevor Thanks for the clarification. That's somewhat different from what your question's wording indicated you were asking. Also, you're correct my solution is not quite what you're looking for, although it does answer your main question of "how similar in size a partitioned primorial can be", which is as close together as the next larger prime that $n$. My suggestion is you ask a new question, making your meaning clear, & link to this one. In the new question, you don't even need to mention $q$ being prime, but just some $n \lt q \lt n^2$. Your requirements on $a,b$ ensure $q$ is prime.